# Android Removing View do not ends its animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-relativelayout, objectanimator

I have added childView with `ObjectAnimator` in `RelativeLayout`. Now when I remove all the child from `RelativeLayout` I still gets `onAnimationEnd` triggered.

How would I stop all the animation of childViews once I removed all the childs from RelativeLayout.

```
RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = getCircleLayoutParam(R.dimen.game_circle_width, R.dimen.game_circle_ht);

container.addView(view, layoutParams);

ObjectAnimator scale = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(view,
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("alpha", 0f),
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 1f),
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("y", 0, mWindowHeight));

scale.setDuration(SPEED_TIME);
scale.start();

scale.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        //Getting triggered even after calling container.removeAllViews()
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
    }
});

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (scale != null){
                            scale.removeAllListeners();
                            scale.cancel();
                            scale.end();
                        }

                        container.removeAllViews();
                        container.invalidate();
                    }
                });
```

On calling `container.removeAllViews()` and `container.invalidate()` on button click. I still gets `onAnimationEnd()` triggered.

Any response is highly appreciated.

Comment: which is the code for removing a child view?

Comment: @0X0nosugar added the button click event

Comment: what is value of `SPEED_TIME`?

Comment: @0X0nosugar Its 4000ms

Comment: do you click on button until animation ends?

Comment: can you invoke clearAnimation()? It helped me once in a RecyclerView... or setAnimation(null) may help. Just a suggestion. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding a `View` to the container, pass the `Animator` as tag:

```
view.setTag(scale);
```

The `OnClickListener`:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

         for (int i = 0; i < container.getChildCount(); i++)
         {
             View v = container.getChildAt(i);
             Object o = v.getTag();
             if (o != null && o instanceof ObjectAnimator)
             {
                 ((ObjectAnimator)o).cancel();
                 // or ...end(), see below
             }
         }
         container.removeAllViews();
         container.invalidate();
     }
});
```

Use `ValueAnimator.cancel()` or `ValueAnimator.end()` depending on which result you want to achieve, see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#cancel%28%29)

If the tag is already in use for some other purpose, one could keep a list with the `ObjectAnimator`s and in the for loop run through that list.

Answer (score 0):

Use [removeAllListeners()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html#removeAllListeners()) or [removeListener(Animator.AnimatorListener listener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html#removeListener(android.animation.Animator.AnimatorListener)) before your calls.

Comment: Thanks but I not removing the animation.Updated my question